# Не могу проскролить саджест WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

К примеру вот, на странице mail:

```
https://health.mail.ru/company/list_moscow/apteki/
```

Нужно выбрать одну станцию метро, Митино. Эта станция не показана, чтобы на нее можно было просто кликнуть, хоть и список доступен.

Вот локатор, с которым видимые элементы кликаются:

```
//div[contains (@class, 'dropdown__item')]/span/span[text()='Авиамоторная'
```

Если можно, то напишите, пожалуйста, полный путь решения. Я нашел информацию, что скролл нужно вызывать при помощи javascript, но нет достаточно знаний как его правильно использовать.

Comment: для начала дайте правильный урл. по этому адресу 404

Comment: на каком языке вы пишете то программу?

Comment: Подправил url Пишу на java. Решение нашел, но буду рад вашим решениям.

Comment: я пишу на vb.net и решения не подойдут, перевести на java код будет сложновато думаю.